# Git blame to find code changes

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Someone broke something but commenting out a line of code but it was done way back then, how do we track that using `git blame`?

Answer (score 2):

If I want to find out who added a specific line of code, and it is relatively unique, I'll typically use:

```
git log -S 'the unique code` --source --stat --all
```

This will tell me when the line was introduced, by who, and the other files modified in the commit.